# apt shim package

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

I noticed in the APT repo there is both shim and shim-signed. I'm wondering what the purpose of the shim package is?

Can it be used to insert a db certificate into the boot process?

I'm looking for an easy way to build a shim EFI with my own test.crt embedded, so that I can boot from a grub EFI that has been signed with my own test.key. Then load the test.crt into the UEFI Firmware as the db.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using GRUB2.06 with `--disable-shim-lock` removes the need for a shim at all